# Hide two buttons and show a different button on xml

Tags: android

I am trying to design the activity layout based on different criteria. I have created the layout on the xml and as a default it shows two buttons(ask, buy) on the activity.

However, in some circumstances, I do not want to show these two buttons, only show a single button which none of them below, totally different button and different action. How could I make it happen?

In other words, I would like to make my new button to stay in middle of buy and ask buttons. with the same size. How should I make it happen ? Instead of two buttons, side by side (buy and ask), now there is only one button (delete) in the center.

```
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAsk"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ask"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="buy"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            />
```

Comment: set it's visibility to `GONE` or `INVISIBLE`

Comment: But where should I put my new button in the xml?

Comment: @texas: put it in same xml file after  `btnBuy ` make by default visibility `GONE` and at run time make it visible and other GONE

Comment: I would like to make my new button to stay in middle of buy and ask buttons. with the same size. How should I make it happen ? Instead of two buttons, side by side (buy and ask), now there is only one button(delete) in the center.

Comment: paste your  screen or complete xml code so, I will provide complete answer.

Comment: @texas: when u make `buy and ask` buttons visibility GONE then third button automatically align center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setVisibility(View.GONE)` in Button object when you want to hide that buttons:

```
Button btnAsk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAsk);
Button btnDel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDel);
Button btnBuy = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBuy);

/* if you want to show only Delete button.. */
btnAsk.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
btnDel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btnBuy.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

/* if you want to show Ask and Buy buttons.. */
btnAsk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btnDel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
btnBuy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

`View.INVISIBLE` attribute will be make your buttons are not shown, but their position is kept.

But `View.GONE` attribute will hide your buttons completely.

Take care of it.

---

If you want to set three buttons, edit your xml code like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAsk"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ask"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDel"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="buy"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would like to make my new button to stay in middle of buy and ask buttons. with the same size. How should I make it happen ? Instead of two buttons, side by side (buy and ask), now there is only one button (delete) in the center.

Comment: Delete button in the center?

Comment: I edit my answer. Edit your xml code like that, then control your buttons in `YourActivity.java`. If you set `View.INVISIBLE`, visible buttons will be kept their position and size. But `View.GONE`, visible buttons will be changed.

Answer (score 1):

To **hide button**, Use `ONE` or `INVISIBLE`

```
Button btnName = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnName);

btnName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

To **visible** button

```
btnName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

In xml use `android:gravity="center"`
or

```
android:centerInParent="true"
```

Comment: I would like to make my new button to stay in middle of buy and ask buttons. with the same size. How should I make it happen ? Instead of two buttons, side by side (buy and ask), now there is only one button (delete) in the center.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:oriantation="horizontal" >
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAsk"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ask"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

     <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="delete"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="buy"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            />

</LinearLayout>

on some condition

delete.setVisibility(View.Visible);
  buy.setVisibility(View.Gone);
  action.setVisibility(View.Gone);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use all your button in XML itself.But make it visible / invisible in your java file ie Activity.In onCreate if you don't want to show make it as an INVISIBLE

```
  Button buyBut=(Button)findViewById(R.id.butBuy);
  buyBut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And make it as an VISIBLE where you need to show it by using the following..

```
 buyBut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout(say userActionLayout) and add your buttons to it,hide this layout when you want to hide these buttons using setVisibility(View.Gone)

Add another button outside this layout(userActionLayout)` and define it differently.Set this Button visible in code when you hide the other layout.

For Example:

```
   <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/userActionLayout"
           android:height="wrap_content"
           android:width="fill_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAsk"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ask"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="buy"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            />
     <LinearLayout/>

     <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOther"
            android:height="wrap_content"
            android:width="fill_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code -

Button buttonname=(Button)findViewById(R.id.butBuy);

> buttonname.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

or -

> buttonname.setVisibility(View.GONE);

show it again with -

> buttonname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);